# How to hide a custom directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to implement tabs with custom directives. This is the code for tabs:

```
<section ng-controller="tabController as tab">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li ng-class="{active: tab.isSelected(1)}"> <a href ng-click="tab.selectTab(1)"> Hosts </a></li>
        <li ng-class="{active: tab.isSelected(2)}"> <a href ng-click="tab.selectTab(2)"> Instances </a></li>
        <li ng-class="{active: tab.isSelected(3)}"> <a href ng-click="tab.selectTab(3)"> Clusters </a></li>
    </ul>
</section>
<host-panel ng-show="tab.isSelected(1)"></host-panel>
```

The tabs are switching correctly as far as I can tell, so the problem probably is not with the tab controller. However, when I use the following line on my custom directive, nothing gets displayed:

```
<host-panel ng-show="tab.isSelected(1)"></host-panel>
```

In fact, neither does wrapping the entire thing in something else work.

```
<div ng-show="tab.isSelected(1)"><host-panel></host-panel>
```

This is the host panel directive:

```
app.directive
('hostPanel',
    function()
    {
        return{
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'partials/hosttable.html',
            controller: 'hostTableController',
            controllerAs: 'table'
        };

    }
);
```

This is the html file

```
<div class = "panel panel-default">
    <table align = "center" class = "table table-striped table-hover" style="max-width: 1600px" ng-controller = "hostTableController as table">
        <tr class = "info">
            <td>ID: </td>
            <td>Name: </td>
            <td>isVirtual: </td>
            <td>OS: </td>
            <td>OS Version: </td>
            <td>Environment ID: </td>
            <td>Operations: </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class = "active" ng-repeat = "host in hosts | orderBy: 'id'">
            <td>{{host.id}}</td>
            <td>{{host.name}}</td>
            <td>{{host.isVirtual}}</td>
            <td>{{host.os}}</td>
            <td>{{host.os_version}}</td>
            <td>{{host.environment_id}}</td>
            <td><div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" aria-hidden="true"> Edit </span></button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"> Delete </span></button>
            </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

So is there a way to make the entire panel hide?

Comment: Is each `host-panel` inside the `section` with the controller? It looks to me like a scoping issue with `tab`. It may be more helpful to your question if you  leave out all the custom directive code, and try to get it to work with even just a normal `<div>` first.

Comment: @4castle The host-panel comes after the section with the controller.
Wait. That was the problem.

Comment: Nice! Glad I could help. Your code looks really solid otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that I was being hilariously dumb.

```
<host-panel ng-show="tab.isSelected(1)"></host-panel>
```

Should go inside the `section` tag with the controller.